# UTplsql returning ora -01031 insufficient priveleges when testing a refcursor as out parameter in procedure

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

I am testing a procedure that has ref cursor as out parameter.But the result says " UNABLE TO RUN : ORA 01031 Insufficient priveleges

Here is my procedure.It is pretty straight forward

```
PROCEDURE pr_plazalist_get(pn_facility_id  IN facility.facilityid%TYPE
                         ,pcur_plaza_info OUT gtcur_plaza_info) IS

   BEGIN
     OPEN pcur_plaza_info FOR
     SELECT p.plazaid      AS plazaid
           ,p.plazanm      AS plazaname
           ,p.plazaacronym AS palazaacronym
       FROM plaza    p
           ,facility f
      WHERE p.facilityid = f.facilityid
        AND f.facilityid = pn_facility_id;

   END pr_plazalist_get;
```

I have declared the type in the spec of the package as follows

```
TYPE gtrec_plaza_info IS RECORD(
   plazaid      plaza.plazaid%TYPE
  ,plazaname    plaza.plazanm%TYPE
  ,plazaacronym plaza.plazaacronym%TYPE);
```

TYPE gtcur_plaza_info IS REF CURSOR RETURN gtrec_plaza_info;

Here is the test package  body for utplsql;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ut_pkg_utility_interface AS
 PROCEDURE ut_setup AS
 BEGIN
  NULL;
 END ut_setup;

PROCEDURE ut_teardown AS
 BEGIN
  NULL;
END ut_teardown;

 PROCEDURE ut_pr_plazalist_get IS
  l_in_params  utplsql_util.utplsql_params;
  l_out_params utplsql_util.utplsql_params;

   BEGIN
  utplsql_util.reg_in_param(par_pos => 1, par_val => 1, params => l_in_params);

  utplsql_util.reg_out_param(par_pos => 2, par_type => 'REFCURSOR', params =>    l_out_params);

  utassert.eq_refc_query(p_msg_nm        => 'refcursor test '
                        ,proc_name       => 'pkg_utility_interface.pr_plazalist_get'
                        ,params          => l_in_params
                        ,cursor_position => 2
                        ,qry             => 'SELECT plazaid,plazanm,plazaacronym from plaza p, facility f
                      where p.plaza.facilityid=facility.facilityid where facility.facilityid=1 ');
 END ut_pr_plazalist_get;

END ut_pkg_utility_interface;
```

When  I am testing it,It is giving me **FAILURE - pkg_utility_interface.UT_PR_PLAZALIST_GET: Unable to run ut_pkg_utility_interface.UT_PR_PLAZALIST_GET: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.** I have my code and test packages in the same schema

Here is my test script
     Begin
     utplsql.test('PKG_UTILITY_INTERFACE',samepackage_in => FALSE,recompile_in => false);
     end;
and this is my result
    .

> FFFFFFF   AA     III  L      U     U RRRRR   EEEEEEE 
>    F        A  A     I   L      U     U R    R  E
>    F       A    A    I   L      U     U R     R E
>    F      A      A   I   L      U     U R     R E
>    FFFF   A      A   I   L      U     U RRRRRR  EEEE
>    F      AAAAAAAA   I   L      U     U R   R   E
>    F      A      A   I   L      U     U R    R  E
>    F      A      A   I   L       U   U  R     R E
>    F      A      A  III  LLLLLLL  UUU   R     R EEEEEEE 
>   . 
>    FAILURE: "PKG_UTILITY_INTERFACE"
>   . 
>   Individual Test Case Results:
>
> FAILURE - PKG_UTILITY_INTERFACE.UT_PR_PLAZALIST_GET: Unable to run ut_PKG_UTILITY_INTERFACE.UT_PR_PLAZALIST_GET: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> Errors recorded in utPLSQL Error Log:
>
> NONE FOUND

Comment: Everything is in the same schema - `pkg_utility_interface` (if that exists and isn't just wrong in the error message), `ut_pkg_utility_interface`, `utplsql_util`, `utassert`, `plaza`, `facility`, anything else I've missed... and the code that calls this? Can you show that too, and the full error stack? It looks like something is catching the exception and losing the context, but it seems like maybe an authid problem somewhere in the chain.

Comment: Initially, a separate schema for unittesting is created called UTP where utplsql is installed. I have my test scripts ut_pkg_utility_interface in UTP and the code to test in another schema. I have granted EXECUTE permission on pkg_utility_interface package to UTP schema. I have executed my test script in the UTP and that gives me error Program named "PKG_UTILITY_INTERFACE" does not exist. SO I wanted to workaround and then took the ut_pkg_utility_interface and put in the schema where pkg_utility_interaface exists.Test script and the error message are included above

Comment: It's still quite hard to follow the relationships here. Everything in the error except the `ORA-01031` itself is being generated by your code, so something is catching that, and apparently squashing the error stack so you can't see what really caused it, which would help. Are `UTP`'s permissions on packages and table in the main schema granted directly, or via a role?

Comment: Permissions on packages are directly granted to UTP not via a role.It looks like the ref cursor is causing a problem. I changed the procedure just to return OUT Parameter instead of refcursor and used utsassert.eq here and it just worked fine. Is there any bug in UTPLSQL that is associated with refcursors?

Answer (score 1):

The "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" is being caused because utPLSQL needs to temporarily create a table. To do so, it uses `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. For this to work, the user needs to have the `CREATE TABLE` privilege granted to them directly, rather than via a role (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/996709).

When using `utplsql_util.reg_in_param` and `utplsql_util.reg_out_param` to setup your parameters, you need to use the same `params` variable. There is also a bit of a typo in the SELECT statement you're comparing against. Your test package body should therefore be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ut_pkg_utility_interface AS
 PROCEDURE ut_setup AS
 BEGIN
  NULL;
 END ut_setup;

PROCEDURE ut_teardown AS
 BEGIN
  NULL;
END ut_teardown;

 PROCEDURE ut_pr_plazalist_get IS
  l_params  utplsql_util.utplsql_params;

   BEGIN
  utplsql_util.reg_in_param(par_pos => 1, par_val => 1, params => l_params);

  utplsql_util.reg_out_param(par_pos => 2, par_type => 'REFCURSOR', params =>    l_params);

  utassert.eq_refc_query(p_msg_nm        => 'refcursor test '
                        ,proc_name       => 'pkg_utility_interface.pr_plazalist_get'
                        ,params          => l_params
                        ,cursor_position => 2
                        ,qry             => 'SELECT plazaid,plazanm,plazaacronym from plaza p, facility f
                      where p.facilityid=f.facilityid and f.facilityid=1 ');
 END ut_pr_plazalist_get;

END ut_pkg_utility_interface;
```

[Full disclosure: I am one of the administrators of the utPLSQL project]