# Oracle procedure within package with alter table throws ORA-01031:insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I get insufficient privileges error when executing a procedure inside a package, even though appropriate access has been granted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DEVELOPER.DDL_PACKS
AS
PROCEDURE disbcons
AS
  BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTER.ADDRESS DISABLE CONSTRAINT PK4';
  END;
END;

GRANT ALTER ON TESTER.ADDRESS TO DEVELOPER;

EXEC developer.ddl.disbcons
```

**EDIT:**
I tried adding `AUTHID DEFINER` in package header. But still i get the `ORA-01031:insufficient privileges` error when executed with `DEVELOPER`. user

Execution works good if i add `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` and execute with the same `DEVELOPER` user. I do not understand why oracle does not consider relevant access when executed with `AUTHID DEFINER`

Comment: how to add `AUTHID DEFINER` for procedures within package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Immediate within a stored procedure keeps giving insufficient priviliges error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996198/execute-immediate-within-a-stored-procedure-keeps-giving-insufficient-priviliges)

Comment: @Vivek - If your procedure is within a package, you can only set `AUTHID` at the package level, not for individual procedures.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong here to down vote. A valid explanation will help to correct rather than silent down vote :|

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks for sharing the question. My procedure is within package, my bad, i must have mentioned it straight forward. I thought the procedure in package or direct doesn't make any difference, but in actual it does. I have corrected my question.

Comment: Isn't Authid definer the default pragma? I think changing to it won't solve your problem. I'm going for the more obvious question: are you sure you have the appropriate access? What were they?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check `EDIT` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vivek you can add AUTHID DEFINER/CURRENT_USER within Package specification only, I think it will work after that, below is your package specification should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DEVELOPER.DDL_PACKS AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS

   PROCEDURE disbcons;

END;
```

Comment: It makes no different since i am already executing with the userid with which i created the package.

Comment: @Vivek could you tell me what is the authorization for the user DEVELOPER? e.g. does the user has DBA role? if not what exactly has?

Comment: @Vivek try CURRENT_USER instead of DEFINER, it will work