# Execute immediate within Oracle Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, execute, sql-grant

I have two users: SASDBA and CDM. 
There is a procedure in schema SASDBA which keeps objects into the buffer pool.
Part of a procedure:

```
BEGIN
              FOR TABLE_ENTRY IN
              (SELECT          *
              FROM dba_tables
              WHERE owner = t_owner
              AND TABLE_NAME    = t_name_obj
              )
              LOOP
EXECUTE immediate 'alter table '||TABLE_ENTRY.OWNER||'.'||TABLE_ENTRY.TABLE_NAME||' storage (buffer_pool keep)';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

So, if I try to pass CDM.TABLE_TEST into the procedure I get an error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

But, if user SASDBA alters it without procedure it works:

```
alter table CDM.TEST_TABLE  storage (buffer_pool keep)
```

> table CDM.TEST_TABLE altered.

Comment: Are you calling the procedure from SASDBA user?

Comment: Same request  ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996198/execute-immediate-within-a-stored-procedure-keeps-giving-insufficient-priviliges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside PL/SQL blocks you have only privileges which are granted to you **directly**. Privileges which are granted through a role (e.g. `DBA`) do not apply inside a PL/SQL block, i.e. a procedure.

Grant privilege directly, for example `GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO SASDBA;`