# I am getting an error due to variable when I execute stored procedure which dynamic PLSQL inside was there in the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, execute-immediate

When I execute stored procedure which contain EXECUTE IMMEDIATE along with create table statement inside the stored procedure then getting error while execute this stored procedure.

Here is the stored procedure -

```
create or replace sp_exec
 as
 .......
 v_mth date;
 .......
begin
 select TO_DATE('01-' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
  INTO v_mth FROM dual;
  execute immediate 'create table tbl_mon_ '||v_mth||' as select ............... from '|| v_mth ||' ..... ';
end;
```

When I try to execute this Stored proc then getting error "**Insufficient Privilege**" at 2nd last line using this code to execute Stored Proc.

```
 begin
  sp_exec;
 end;
```

then getting error which mentioned below:-

```
 ORA-01031: Insufficient privilege
 ORA-06512: at sp_exec line 11  --here line 11 mention for Execute immediate
 ORA-06512: at line 2         -- here mention for sp_exec in the PLSQL block
```

I am working in the user schema itself so I've all types of privileges even `CREATE TABLE` statement also. When I run outside the stored procedure (PL/SQL block) then dynamic table have been created.

Comment: Inside a OL/SQL block only directly granted privileges apply. Privileges which are granted by role (e. g. DBA) do not apply.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I have already all types of `GRANT` privilege for this user schema. I have checked in `session_privs` table.

Comment: *"This stored proc is in user schema itself means all types of GRANT privileges have"* - That's not right. Appropriate privileges should have been granted **directly** to the user to read or write a particular **database object**, like a table. Go through both the answers I added, you'll know.

Comment: What is your exact error message (I know only `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` which may appear when you install an Oracle on your machine) and what is the SQL statement? As far as I remember you should get an `ORA-39034: Table ... string does not exist` if you try to select a table where privileges are missing. Maybe list also the privileges you have been granted.

Comment: I would also expect `select any table` privilege.

Comment: Again, please provide the exact and full error message and the generated SQL string. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Instead of `SESSION_PRIVS` better select `USER_SYS_PRIVS` and `USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit when i check using `USER_SYS_PRIVS` then able to `select any table` as privilege but `ADMIN_OPTION` as **NO**.

Comment: You don't provide needed information, I am out for this question.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've updated all the code. Due to variable getting error when i execute stored proc. In `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` i am using variable in the stored proc. Due to this variable getting error. Please see

Comment: Run `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);` before the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Can you run the dynamic statement manually?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the suggestion. But at the time of creation of dynamic tables I did it but getting the error.

Comment: Then ask your DBA for the missing privileges. Once again, the privileges has to be granted **directly** to the user not via a ROLE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196687/discussion-between-wernfried-domscheit-and-md-wasi).